# Laravel 5.1: Run Custom Artisan Command in Background

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan, ratchet

I'm working on a chat application using the [Ratchet package](http://socketo.me/). With the help of tutorials I've written a custom artisan command to start the Websocket server. I need to run this Artisan command in the background and it should be running all the time. How do I do it?

I tried using [Artisan::queue and Artisan::call](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#calling-commands-outside-of-cli) from Artisan Facade. But since my custom command runs indefinitely(for a long time) it isn't working.

**Edit:**

My hosting provider is not allowing me to run Artisan commands through ssh.

Here is the code for the Custom Artisan Command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Classes\Socket\ChatSocket;
use App\Classes\Socket\Base\BaseSocket;

class ChatServer extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'chat_server:serve';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->info("Start server");

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new ChatSocket()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply should run it in console with command:

```
php artisan chat_server:serve
```

And probably you should make sure it will work all the time. One of the ways is using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to make sure this command will run (almost) all the time

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't have access to 'Artisan' commands through ssh in my shared hosting  account.

Comment: I tried using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216857/execute-laravel-symfony-artisan-command-in-background. But I couldn't get it working.

Comment: I'm afraid it cannot be done easily. In theory you can in crone (assuming you have cron) run for example in 1 minute `$server->run();` and `$server->stop();` but it won't be very reliable so you should consider moving to VPS hosting where you can run commands in cron and make sure they are running all the time

Comment: Thanks. I'm considering to use AWS which has 1 year free plan.